# Hibernate and dynamical wrapper for entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Probably a common problem, but anyway:

Let's say I have a simple entity Task with a list of Activity entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private List<Activity> activities;
}
```

And Activity entity is pretty simple:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity")
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "activity_type")
    private int type;
}
```

And here I want to do some magic -- based on Activity type I want hibernate to stuff Task.activities with different Activity implementation, for example if Activity.type == 1, I want to have ActivityAImpl there, if Activity.type == 2 - it should be ActivityBImpl and so on.. Basically all my activities would implement a single interface with a some method "execute()".

Hopefully there is a simple solution for that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at @MappedSuperClass and @Discriminator annotions. I guess that is what you are looking for. Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/MarkAbstractEntityWithMappedSuperclass.htm).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity)
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "activity_type")
public abstract class Activity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "activity_type")
    private int type;

    public abstract void execute();
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class ActivityImplA extends Activity {

     public void execute() {
        .... Impl a
     }

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class ActivityImplB extends Activity {

     public void execute() {
        .... Impl b
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's definitely what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how should I retrieve an Activity then? When I do:

`(Activity) getCurrentSession().get(Activity.class, id);`

it throws: `Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: com.xxx.Activity `

Comment: I think the get(class, id) will not work. Because it will try to create an instance of the abstract class. Use a query instead, like `getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT a FROM Activity a WHERE a.id = :id").setParam("id",id).uniqueResult();`

Comment: No it works fine now, I just forgot to mention my child-classed in annotatedClasses :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Did not test this, but I think this should work...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity")
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "activity_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Activity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class ActivityImpl1 extends Activity {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class ActivityImpl2 extends Activity {

}
```

Comment: Thanks! It compiles, but when I do:

`(Activity) getCurrentSession().get(Activity.class, id);`

it throws: `Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: com.xxx.Activity`

Comment: That's normal. Activity is an abstract class... you should do getCurrentSession().get(ActivityImpl1.class, id)